# Recursive functions and pattern matching in ocaml

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

The following code snippet comes from the official OCaml [website](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/99problems.html):

```
# let rec compress = function
| a :: (b :: _ as t) -> if a = b then compress t else a :: compress t
| smaller -> smaller;;
val compress : 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>
```

The above function 'compresses' a list with consecutive, duplicative elements, e.g. :

```
# compress ["a";"a";"a";"a";"b";"c";"c";"a";"a";"d";"e";"e";"e";"e"];;

- : string list = ["a"; "b"; "c"; "a"; "d"; "e"]
```

I'm having a devil of a time understanding the logic of the above code. I'm used to coding imperatively, so this recursive, functional approach, combined with OCamls laconic - but obscure - syntax is causing me to struggle.

For example, where is the base case? Is it `smaller -> smaller`? I know `smaller` is a variable, or an identifier, but what is it returning (is returning even the right term in OCaml for what's happening here)?

I know that lists in OCaml are singly linked, so I'm also wondering if a new list is being generated, or if elements of the existed list are being cut? Since OCaml is functional, I'm inclined to think that lists are not mutable - is that correct? If you want to change a list, you essentially need to generate a new list with the elements you're seeking to add (or with the elements you're seeking to excise absent). Is this a correct understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the base case is this:

```
| smaller -> smaller
```

The first pattern of the `match` expression matches any list of length 2 or greater. (It would be good to make sure you see why this is the case.)

Since OCaml matches patterns in order, the base case matches lists of lengths 0 and 1. That's why the programmer chose the name `smaller`. They were thinking "this is some smaller list".

The parts of a match statement look like this in general:

```
| pattern -> result
```

Any names in the pattern are bound to parts of the value matched against the pattern (as you say). So `smaller` is bound to the whole list. So in sum, the second part of the `match` says that if the list is of length 0 or 1, the result should just be the list itself.

Lists in OCaml are immutable, so it's not possible for the result of the function to be a modified version of the list. The result is a new list, unless the list is already a short list (of length 0 or 1).

So, what you say about the immutability of OCaml lists is exactly correct.

Comment: Thank you, this is immensely clarifying. As for why the first match case matches lists of length >= 2, I think it's because of `a :: (b :: _ as t)`.